# What is the problem with this Java code dealing with Generics?

Tags: java, generics

```
interface Addable<E> {
    public E add(E x);
    public E sub(E y);
    public E zero();
}

class SumSet<E extends Addable> implements Set<E> {

    private E element;

    public SumSet(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public E getSum() {
        return element.add(element.zero());
    }
}
```

It seems that `element.add()` doesn't return an `E extends Addable` but rather an `Object`. Why is that? Has it anything to do with Java not knowing at run-time what the object types really are, so it just assumes them to be Objects(thus requiring a cast)?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for posting a code snippet that can be easily cut and pasted to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
class SumSet<E extends Addable<E>> implements Set<E> {
```

Your original code specifies that each element of SumSet must be an instance of E, a class that implements `Addable` (which is equivalent to `Addable<Object>`).  By changing `Addable` to `Addable<E>`, you're specifying that add, sub, and zero methods of the E class must accept and return instances of E (rather than just Object).

Note that the E type variable in SumSet has nothing to do with the above E variable.  So:

```
class SumSet<T extends Addable<T>> implements Set<T> {

    private T element;

    public SumSet(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public T getSum() {
        return element.add(element.zero());
    }
}
```

works fine too.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
class SumSet<E extends Addable<E>> implements Set<E> {
```

I don't know if this is exactly what you mean but basically the problem is that you're using `Addable` in the declaration of `SumSet` as a raw type. That strips off all generic parameter types and makes `Addable` appear to `SumSet` as:

```
interface Addable {
  Object add(Object x);
  Object sub(Object y);
  Object zero();
}
```

Obviously `Object` is not an `E`, hence the error. See [What is the raw type?](http://tinyurl.com/y7bvt2e) from the Java Generics FAQ.

On a side note `public` is unnecessary on methods in interface definitions.

Comment: Type erasure strikes again! @devoured: Java has no idea what generics are at runtime, so it just ignores them then. This occasionally results in fun bugs like this one.

Comment: On a side note `public` is unnecessary on methods in **public** interface definitions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to say `<E extends Addable<E>>`, not `<E extends Addable>`.

This is because when using a raw type, all references to its (non-existent) type parameters get erased.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a `SumSet` class that implements `Set`, you might want to consider whether you can get what you need by writing a method that can sum all of the elements in the set.

```
public static <T extends Addable<T> > T sum(Set<T> set)
{
    T sum = null;
    for (T t : set)
    {
        if (sum == null)
        {
            sum = t;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum.add(t);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```